# R packages installations give a `::std::isxdigit' declared here fatal error`

Tags: c++, r, macos, rcpp, install.packages

I recently updated the **Homebrew** on my Mac (10.14.6 (18G6020)), and went ahead to recompile the development version of R.  I built an installation script to make sure the same steps are taken every time (see below).  R compiles successfully and passes all checks.  However, when I begin to install packages, such as `Rcpp`, `devtools`, `ape`, `lme4`, among others, I get a `::std::isxdigit declared here`  during the compilation, and installation fails.

I'm posting here the error message for Rcpp, installation script, sessionInfo(), and brew version.  Any help to resolve this will be much appreciated,

Thank you !

#### Error message for Rcpp:

```
  * installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
  ** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs
  clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks//R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr\
    /local/opt/icu4c/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/curl/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/cairo/include -I/usr/local/opt/pango/include/pa\
    ngo-1.0/pango -I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O3  -c api.cpp -o api.o
  In file included from api.cpp:24:
  In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27:
  In file included from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:51:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
 In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:216:
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:116:20: error: use
       of undeclared identifier 'LC_COLLATE_MASK'
         collate  = LC_COLLATE_MASK,
                    ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:117:20: error: use
       of undeclared identifier 'LC_CTYPE_MASK'
         ctype    = LC_CTYPE_MASK,
                    ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:118:20: error: use
       of undeclared identifier 'LC_MONETARY_MASK'
         monetary = LC_MONETARY_MASK,
                    ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:119:20: error: use
       of undeclared identifier 'LC_NUMERIC_MASK'
         numeric  = LC_NUMERIC_MASK,
                    ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:120:20: error: use
       of undeclared identifier 'LC_TIME_MASK'
         time     = LC_TIME_MASK,
                    ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:121:20: error: use
       of undeclared identifier 'LC_MESSAGES_MASK'
         messages = LC_MESSAGES_MASK,
                    ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:330:5: error:
       unknown type name 'locale_t'; did you mean 'locale'?                                                                                                                    
     locale_t __l;                                                                                                                                                             
     ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:105:24: note:
       'locale' declared here
 class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS locale
                        ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:349:5: error:
       unknown type name 'locale_t'; did you mean 'locale'?       
     locale_t __l;                                                                                                                                                             
     ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:105:24: note:
       'locale' declared here
 class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS locale
                        ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:708:5: error:
       unknown type name 'locale_t'; did you mean 'locale'?                                                                                                                    
     locale_t __l;                                                                                                                                                             
     ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:105:24: note:
       'locale' declared here
 class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS locale
                        ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:726:5: error:
       unknown type name 'locale_t'; did you mean 'locale'?                                                                                                                    
     locale_t __l;                                                                                                                                                             
     ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:105:24: note:
       'locale' declared here
 class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS locale
                        ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:958:5: error:
       unknown type name 'locale_t'; did you mean 'locale'?                                                                                                                    
     locale_t __l;                                                                                                                                                             
     ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:105:24: note:
       'locale' declared here
 class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS locale
                        ^
 In file included from api.cpp:24:
 In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27:
 In file included from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:51:
 In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:40:
 In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:163:
 In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:140:
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/locale:739:26: error: use of
       undeclared identifier 'strtoll_l'
         long long __ll = strtoll_l(__a, &__p2, __base, _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE);                                                                                                 
                          ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/locale:779:35: error: use of
       undeclared identifier 'strtoull_l'
         unsigned long long __ll = strtoull_l(__a, &__p2, __base, _LIBCPP_GET...
                                   ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/locale:808:12: error: use of
       undeclared identifier 'strtof_l'
     return strtof_l(__a, __p2, _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE);                                                                                                                         
            ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/locale:814:12: error: use of
       undeclared identifier 'strtod_l'
     return strtod_l(__a, __p2, _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE);                                                                                                                         
            ^
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/locale:820:12: error: use of
       undeclared identifier 'strtold_l'; did you mean 'strtoll'?                                                                                                              
     return strtold_l(__a, __p2, _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE);                                                                                                                        
           ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:117:9: note:
      'strtoll' declared here
using ::strtoll;                                                                                                                                                              
        ^
In file included from api.cpp:24:
In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:51:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:40:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:163:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:140:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/locale:1094:9: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'sscanf_l'
    if (__libcpp_sscanf_l(__buf.c_str(), _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE, "%p", &__v) != 1)
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/__bsd_locale_defaults.h:35:61: note:
      expanded from macro '__libcpp_sscanf_l'
#define __libcpp_sscanf_l(...)                              sscanf_l(__VA_ARGS__)
                                                            ^
In file included from api.cpp:24:
In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:51:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:40:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:163:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:140:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/locale:1199:18: error: use of
      undeclared identifier 'isxdigit_l'; did you mean 'isxdigit'?                                                                                                            
            if (!isxdigit_l(*__ns, _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE))
                 ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cctype:115:9: note:
      'isxdigit' declared here
using ::isxdigit;                                                                                                                                                             
        ^
In file included from api.cpp:24:
In file included from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27:
In file included from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:51:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:40:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/istream:163:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/ostream:140:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/locale:1199:18: error: too
      many arguments to function call, expected 1, have 2; did you mean                                                                                                       
      '::std::isxdigit'?
            if (!isxdigit_l(*__ns, _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE))
                 ^~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/cctype:115:9: note:
      '::std::isxdigit' declared here
using ::isxdigit;                                                                                                                                                             
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [api.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/Rcpp’
ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘minqa’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/minqa’
ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/RcppEigen’
ERROR: dependencies ‘minqa’, ‘nloptr’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘RcppEigen’ are not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/lme4’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/private/var/folders/f7/v_vt_5bn07z9tljnh56n9crnrzdbg9/T/RtmpuouQQU/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("lme4") :
  installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("lme4") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("lme4") :
  installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("lme4") :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("lme4") :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
```

#### Installation script

```
## remove binaries, etc                                                                                                                                                        
make distclean
## update                                                                                                                                                                      
svn update
## get recommended tools                                                                                                                                                       
./tools/rsync-recommended

## other variables                                                                                                                                                             
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/
JAVA_CPPFLAGS="-I/${JAVA_HOME}/include -I/${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin"
JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/server"
JAVA_LIBS="-L/${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/server -ljvm"

export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/curl/include -\
   I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/cairo/include -I/usr/local/opt/pango/include/pango-1.0/pango -I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/curl/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"

export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
export FC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
export OBJC=clang
export CFLAGS='-Wall -g -O3'
export CXXFLAGS='-Wall -g -O3'
export OBJCFLAGS='-Wall -g -O3'
export FFLAGS='-Wall -g -O3 -mtune=generic'
export LC_ALL='C'

./configure --enable-R-framework=/Library/Frameworks/ \
            --with-blas="-framework Accelerate" --with-lapack \
            --x-includes=/opt/X11/include --x-libraries=/opt/X11/lib \
            --with-internal-tzcode --with-cairo=yes

make

make install
```

#### R session

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2020-09-29 r79274)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.0 tools_4.1.0    tcltk_4.1.0
```

#### Hombrew Version

```
bash-3.2$ brew --version
Homebrew 2.5.2
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision f5bfb; last commit 2020-09-25)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision a5844b; last commit 2020-09-25)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.  Sorry but hear you are having issues but "I recently updated the Homebrew on my Mac" shows that you are using a not-formally-supported installation to build R, and then R packages. Please try maybe the [R Installation and Adminstration](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html) manual (and its macOS appendix / sections) and/or the [r-sig-mac](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mac) list.

Comment: Thank you for your message, I should have specified:  I use hombrew to install tcl-tk, gfortran (which changed the dynlib from v .3 to .6), Cairo and Tiff libraries, not to install R.    R is downloaded from the svn repo (per R installation and Administration `svn checkout https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/ R_dev`, and compiled following using the script above which is based on the R Installation and Administration manual for macOS over the years.  R compiles successfully and passes `make check`.  The issues arise w/packages, e.g. Rcpp.  Again, any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Additional details:  Installation script follows the Appendix Sections C.3.2 to C.3.6.  Thanks again,

Comment: We should be able to help with Rcpp then because it is both not exactly brand-new and somewhat tested, and also rather widely used with both `clang++` and `g++`.  It may be header-ordering, or it may be some defines.  I am not a macOS user so to expose your issue to mac experts I still think you should try either `r-sig-mac` (though they may be hostile to you using homebrew rather than their toolchain) or our rcpp-devel list.

Comment: Lastly, per Occam's Razor: start with the most obvious and try to get of the LC_COLLATE messages. You don't have a locale set.  Try fixing that first, then try again.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, based on your comments I seem to have fixed the issue.  I downloaded an [xlocale.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-800.0.38/src/projects/libcxx/include/support/ibm/xlocale.h.auto.html) header; then sourced it into the default locale.h header w/ `#include_next <xlocale.h>`, and removed the `--with-internal-tzcode` argument.  Thank you for your thoughts, this helped out significatly.  Did you make changes in Rcpp ?  Best

Comment: No, Rcpp needs no changes.  Also, my (fairly large system with a fair number of developer packages) does not have file `xlocale.h` anywhere ...

Comment: Ok, I'll check again removing the xlocale.h.  The header had the definitions for the locale env variables listed on the error file.  If that's what was missing before, probably explains why it was failing before.  Thanks again for your advice